# join historical fire occurrence data in two tables by complex join on range of values

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, join

I am trying to link two different historical wildfire occurrence tables together to analyze data from one table (number of firefighters assigned) to the data from the other table (modeled fire parameters). There are over 20,000 records in table 1 and 50,000 records in table 2. I want to keep all records for table 1 and discard the unmatched records. For those with a match, it is a one-to-one relationship.

Here's where I'm having trouble; there is no unique identifier linking the two tables together. Fire name and fire number fields are different between two tables. I need to get the best possible join using other available spatial and temporal fields to assess whether I have a sufficient sample for the population (i.e. avoid manual matching). I want to join based on year, state, and jurisdiction - these should be straightforward, but will return many records that are mismatched multiple times.

To minimize mismatching, I also want to join on fire size and fire start date. Because of the way these data are reported, they may not match exactly between the 2 tables; therefore, I want to join these values on a range of dates and a range of areas. Finally, because fire sizes range from less than an acres to tens of thousands of acres (potentially more), the size of the moving window for fire acreage needs to be relative to the fire size itself. This is well beyond the scope of my Access/SQL skill set.

I have included 2 sample tables. 
For this example, the first 5 records in each table should match up (in order) with each other, i.e. these are the same fires, even though the startDOY (day of year) and finalAcres values are slightly different. For the sake of providing an example, the next 5 records in Table 2 demonstrate what would be associated erroneously with the first 5 records in Table 1 if the tables were joined just on state, jurisdiction and fire year.

I need a code to properly join both tables where:

```
    Table1.state = Table2.state2
    Table1.jurisdiction = Table2.jurisdiction2
    Table1.fireYear = Table2.fireYear2
    abs(Table1.startDOY-Table2.startDOY2) <=7
    (((Table1.finalAcres-Table2.finalAcres2)/(abs((Table1.finalAcres+Table2.finalAcres2)/2)))*100) <= 10% 
    #my attempt at expressing a 10% percent difference in size values between two tables
```

Table 1.

```
    idx fireName    fireNum fireYear    startDOY    finalAcres  state   jurisdiction
    1   Stump       1       2010        190         750         NV      wfo
    2   Stump       2       2010        210         20          ID      sst
    3   Stump       3       2009        211         10          CA      sst
    4   Stump       4       2010        255         10000       CO      ref
    5   Stump       5       2010        270         0.1         MT      cpx
```

Table 2.

```
    idx fireName2   fireNum2    fireYear2   startDOY2   finalAcres2 state2 jurisdiction2
    1   Stump2      100         2010        195         751         NV     wfo
    2   Stump3      99          2010        211         22          ID     sst
    3   Stump_1     88          2009        215         10.5        CA     sst
    4   Stump Fire  77          2010        255         10020       CO     ref
    5   01Stump     66          2010        270         0.2         MT     cpx
    6   Stumps      55          2010        111         0.1         NV     wfo
    7   Stump22     44          2010        55          0.1         ID     sst
    8   Stump6      33          2009        66          0.1         CA     sst
    9   Stump01     22          2010        77          0.1         CO     ref
    10  StumpFire   11          2010        88          500         MT     cpx
```

Comment: Why are their two tables !?!

Comment: And what good are 2 tables that are related but don't have a Primary Key?!?  Who designed this mess, Obama?!?

Comment: 2 tables because fire records came from different sources,  e.g. federal vs. non-federal.  Neither is 100% complete and both have fields of interest.  I want the overlap between the tables. Agreed that these are a mess from data management perspective,  but it is what is available.

Comment: These are what's referred to as "fuzzy joins".  I can't say I'm knowledgeable, and I'm not goin gto do the google legwork because I've got work to do for my full-time job, but that search term may be useful.